# NullPointerException when reading file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, polynomials

I am writing a program that requires me to read in a predetermined file and add the numbers given into polynomial format. I keep getting a NullPointerException when the code reaches the end of a file. Here is the snippit of code that gives me the error:

The error is occurring on line 11 and/or 12.

```
public IList<Integer, Term> add(IList<Integer, Term> p1, IList<Integer, Term> p2)
{
    IList<Integer, Term> addList = new LList<Integer, Term>();

    //If the keys of both list equal each other, add them to the term 
    //being placed inside of addList

    //
    if(p1.getSize() >= p2.getSize() || p2.getSize() <= p1.getSize()){
     //Here is where the error is happening --v
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if(p1.find(i).equals(p2.find(i))){
                Term t1 = p1.find(i);
                Term t2 = p2.find(i);

                int c1 = t1.getCoef();
                int c2 = t2.getCoef();
                int c3 = c1 + c2;

                Term t3 = new Term(c3, i);

                //Add the added term, at the location of the previously added terms location
                addList.add(i, t3);
            }
        }
    }
    return addList;
}
```

Any help with this program will be more than helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please identify the specific line where the NPE occurs. The line number will be in the stack trace that Java barfs to console when the problem occurs.

Comment: To re-iterate, Please identify the specific line where the NPE occurs.

Comment: If `p1` or `p2` is null then the problem is with the calling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IList<Integer, Term> add(IList<Integer, Term> p1, IList<Integer, Term> p2)
{
    IList<Integer, Term> addList = new LList<Integer, Term>();

    if (p1 == null || p2 == null) {
        return addList;
    }

    if(p1.getSize() >= p2.getSize() || p2.getSize() <= p1.getSize()){
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```